# Getting reference of mEdit in ListAdapter class

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, onclicklistener, listadapter

This is my Custom List Adapter Class :

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private int resourceId;
    String name="";
    String phone;
    private ArrayList<String> sites = null;
    private Context context;


    private static  class ViewHolder{
        TextView RideDetails;
        EditText mEdit;
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> objects,String phone) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resourceId = resource;
        this.sites = objects;
        this.phone=phone;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return sites.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sites.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        name = getItem(position);
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_resource, parent, false);
        }
        TextView mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ridedetails);
        mTextView.setText(name);
        Button mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Name",name);
                String ridetrackno=name.substring(name.indexOf(":")+1,name.indexOf("Source")-2);

                EditText mEdit;
                mEdit   = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.PriceQuotation);
                String fare=mEdit.getText().toString();


                String myUrl=".....API URL....."+phone+"/"+ridetrackno+"/"+fare;
                Log.d("URL",myUrl);
                HttpGetRequest getRequest = new HttpGetRequest();
                try{
                    String result = getRequest.execute(myUrl).get();
                    Log.d("Details:",result);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

This is my resource_file in which items are injected through REST API :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="5dip">
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ridedetails"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip">
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Quote Price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/PriceQuotation"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ridedetails"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip">
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/PriceQuotation"
        android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/PriceQuotation"
        android:text="Button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Structure of List View :

Each list item is composed of a TextView(whose details I am able to get),Edit Text(causing Exception) and a simple button whose onClick function has been written.

**Now I am facing two problems:**

1. ***mEdit Reference*** :  The program is failing with a null pointer exception when I am trying to get the text entered in Edit Text when button in a list item is clicked.
2. ***Always Last List Item is picked up*** : Irrespective of which button is clicked, the content of last TextView is only returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Adapter will get  all views in getView method at once, you trying to getting edittext in button click listener

write this line outside button click listener

```
final EditText mEdit   = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.PriceQuotation);
```

2.

```
final TextView mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ridedetails);
```

Inside button click listener

```
String vlaue = mTextView.getText().toString();
```

getView() Code :

```
@Override
public View getView ( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    name = getItem(position);
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_resource, parent, false);
    }

    final TextView mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ridedetails);
    mTextView.setText(name);

    final EditText mEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.PriceQuotation);

    Button mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String vlaue = mTextView.getText().toString();

            Log.d("Name", vlaue);

            String ridetrackno = vlaue.substring(vlaue.indexOf(":") + 1, vlaue.indexOf("Source") - 2);
            String fare = mEdit.getText().toString();

            String myUrl = ".....API URL....." + phone + "/" + ridetrackno + "/" + fare;
            Log.d("URL", myUrl);
            HttpGetRequest getRequest = new HttpGetRequest();
            try {
                String result = getRequest.execute(myUrl).get();
                Log.d("Details:", result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Now I am able to fetch the text set in EditText. Please also help me out with the second problem wherein no matter which button I click,always the last item in list gets picked up.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to put `EditText mEdit` either out of the `Button`'s `onClick()` event or you need to change object name of `view` as coded below

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    name = getItem(position);
    View childView = convertView;
    if (childView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_resource, parent, false);
    }
    TextView mTextView = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.ridedetails);
    mTextView.setText(name);
    Button mButton = (Button) childView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText mEdit = (EditText) childView.findViewById(R.id.PriceQuotation);
        }
    });

}
```

Because `view` will be referred inside as button hence we named the main view to `childView`.

This will not give you `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

For 2. inside `onClick` Try :

```
String namePos = getItem(position);

ridetrackno=namePos.substring(namePos.indexOf(":")+1,namePos.indexOf("Source")-2);
```

Hope this helps